# Wordpress slide down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i tried to implement a jquery slide down menu in my wordpress blog.
Sadly it is not working at all. I will show the submenu when i click on the parent menu point. Here is my html code:

```
    <ul id="menu-sidebarmenue" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-37"><a href="#">Parentmenu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="?page_id=13">Submenu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

my Css:

```
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu-item {    
    width: 225px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: black dotted 1px;
}
.sub-menu { 
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
```

and my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {

        //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
        $('.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('on');

        //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');

        //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

            //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
            $(this).addClass('on');

            //OPEN THE SLIDE
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         } 

     });


    /*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

    //ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
    $('.menu-item-has-children').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');

    //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
    });

    /*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/


    /********************************************************************************************************************
    CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
    ********************************************************************************************************************/   
    $('.sub-menu').hide();

});
```

can anyone help me with my code? 
Would be very nice. Thank you a lot!

EDIT:: 
Hi, i got the problem now when i have more than one dropdown menu and i click on one, that all other open as well. can you help me how i can fix this that just .this object slides down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the jQuery you are using is referencing to HTML elements that you do not use.

In your HTML, there are no classes `on` or `off`.

Also, you only have **one** slide, so the functions for closing slides do not work correctly.

If you just want to toggle the `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` animations on the submenu, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    
    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {

        $('.sub-menu').slideToggle('normal');
        
     });
});
```

This works for a simple sliding animation. See what I mean in this demo:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/62t57gwy/)

Comment: Hi, i got the problem now when i have more than one dropdown menu and i click on one, that all other open as well. can you help me how i can fix this that just .this object slides down?

Comment: Try replacing `$('.sub-menu').slideToggle('normal');` with `$(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('normal');`

Comment: ahh i thought about something with .next() but .find() is a better solution. Thank you

Comment: @Crag No problem. You could even write it as `$('.sub-menu', this).slideToggle('normal');` which is the shorthand version of the `.find()`